# MouseWheel event not scrolling in increments of 120

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseevent

I've hooked up a MouseWheel event to one of my controls, but I discovered that `e.Delta` is not always a multiple of 120, particularly when I scroll it a lot. I get numbers like "131" and "-394".

Why's that? How can I fix it? It's causing problems with my program where the number (divided by 120) doesn't correlate to the actual number of notches ticked.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you cannot rely on the delta being 120 any more. [Here's a post about the same issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/gametechnologiesgeneral/thread/1deb5f7e-95ee-40ac-84db-58d636f601c7/).

And [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617.aspx):

> The delta was set to 120 to allow Microsoft or other vendors to build finer-resolution wheels (a freely-rotating wheel with no notches) to send more messages per rotation, but with a smaller value in each message. To use this feature, you can either add the incoming delta values until WHEEL_DELTA is reached (so for a delta-rotation you get the same response), or scroll partial lines in response to the more frequent messages. You can also choose your scroll granularity and accumulate deltas until it is reached.

Comment: I should have stated that I am using a notched-mouse though. It pretty much always gives me 120 when I only roll it one-tick, but when I roll it multiple ticks really quickly, it gives me odd numbers. It's a Microsoft mouse too. Accumulator doesn't work well when scrolling back and forth, a single notch might add up to a full 120 because of how the numbers turn out...but now that I think about it, separate accumulators for + and - might work !

Comment: Giving this further thought, it might make sense to reset the accumulator to 0 after a short period of inactivity and when switching directions.